# Query optimization of oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I don't have much knowledge on query optimization, I need some help here. here is sample code of our project, its long running oracle query to pull data from 2 different tables (student, student_info).

Is there any possibility to optimize this? How do the `where` clause 'and' operation work here?

Does it maintain any order while executing AND clause? How the below query make the different before and after by removing the code of line `b.student_id in ('a123','b123','c123')`.

We don't have the privileges to add indexes on that table columns.

How can we improve the performance without creating indexes.

```
select a.student_id
       max(decode(a.marks_limit, 99.99,100,null )) as max_marks,
       b.student_city_code "NYC",
from student a, 
     student_info b
where a.student_id=b.student_id
  and a.student_id in ('a123','b123','c123')
  and b.student_id in ('a123','b123','c123')
  and  b.adress_modified > TO_TIMESTAMP('2003/12/13 10:13:18', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
  group by a.student_id, b.student_city_code;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: SQL Server or Oracle?? Which one?

Comment: How many records in `student`? How many in `student_info`?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
select a.student_id
    max(decode(a.marks_limit, 99.99,100,null )) as max_marks,
    b.student_city_code "NYC",
from student a
join student_info b
  on a.student_id=b.student_id     -- explicit join
where a.student_id in ('a123','b123','c123') -- removing duplicate condition
  and b.adress_modified>TO_TIMESTAMP('2003/12/13 10:13:18','YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
group by a.student_id, b.student_city_code;
```

And add indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX id1 ON student(student_id);
CREATE INDEX id2 ON student_info(student_id);
CREATE INDEX id3 ON student_info(adress_modified);
```

Comment: Its remote database and we dont rights to add index on that table columns. Thanks

Comment: join operation make the difference in the executin time of the query?

Comment: @user1272269 explicit JOIN is preferred way over comma syntax(no performance gain)

Comment: @user1272269 -  When you say *"Its remote database"* do you mean it's another database and you're querying across a database link into a local database? Or was that just a misusage? Clarity is crucial because tuning distributed transactions is very different from tuning queries in one database.

Answer (score 0):

First, write the query using proper, explicit, **proper** `JOIN` syntax with sensible table aliases and `case` expressions.

After fixing it up, I would expect something like this:

```
select s.student_id
       max(s.marks_limit) as max_marks,  -- I have no idea what the decode() is supposed to be doing
       si.student_city_code
from student s join
     student_info si
     on s.student_id = si.student_id
where s.student_id in ('a123', 'b123', 'c123')
 and   si.adress_modified > TIMESTAMP '2003-12-13T10:13:18'HH:MI:SS')
group by s.student_id, si.student_city_code;
```

I would start with indexes on `student(student_id)` and `student_info(student_id address_modified, student_city_code)`.

Comment: join operation make the difference in the executin time of the query?

Comment: @user1272269 . . . No.  It makes a difference in understanding the query.  Plus, it is like using modern English versus Shakespearean English.  `JOIN` is the right way to express explicit `JOIN`s between tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just some suggestions.

Yuo have already   a.student_id=b.student_id  so the condizione b.student_id in ('a123,'b123','c123')  is just an useful repetition 
You  shoudl also using explict join notation and not old implict notation based on where clause

```
   select a.student_id
    max(decode(a.marks_limit, 99.99,100,null )) as max_marks,
    b.student_city_code "NYC",
    from student a
    INNER JOIN  student_info b ON a.student_id= b.student_id
    WHERE 
    and a.student_id in ('a123','b123','c123')
    and  b.adress_modified > TO_TIMESTAMP('2003/12/13 10:13:18', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
    group by a.student_id, b.student_city_code
```

and for better performance you should check for a composite index  on table

```
 student_info ( adress_modified, student_id )
```

or

```
student_info ( adress_modified, student_id, student_city_code )
```

Comment: " condition b.student_id in ('a123,'b123','c123') is just an useful repetition" Is that make any diffrence in the performance(time of execution) of the query?

Comment: join operation make the difference in the executin time of the query?

Comment: try and let me know  ..  ..as in my answer  these are mainly suggestion  .. (anyway if the query optimizer  work in a smart way  should not make difference  .. ) .. but as suggested  the condition is redundant and confusing

Comment: For the JOIN  ..no .. old where clause sintax or  INNER JOIN clause sintax  are the same for performance  .. .. performance are related  mainly to indexes.. so you should use composite index  based on most selective column left  to right and last column not involved  in where but used in select